# NFS on Godaddy VPS

Tags: vps, nfs, godaddy

I'm having big trouble trying to setup nfs sharing folder between 2 VPS I have on GoDaddy, Tried to follow lots of step-by-step guides to do this, but I can't start NFS service, I get this error when trying to start:

```
FATAL: Module nfsd not found.
FATAL: Error running install command for nfsd
Starting NFS services:                                     [  OK  ]
Starting NFS quotas:                                       [  OK  ]
Starting NFS mountd:                                       [  OK  ]
Stopping RPC idmapd:                                       [  OK  ]
Starting RPC idmapd:                                       [  OK  ]
Starting NFS daemon: rpc.nfsd: Unable to access /proc/fs/nfsd errno 2 (No such file or directory).
Please try, as root, 'mount -t nfsd nfsd /proc/fs/nfsd' and then restart rpc.nfsd to correct the problem
                                                           [FAILED]
```

Also if I try to mount that line:

```
mount -t nfsd nfsd /proc/fs/nfsd
```

I get:

```
mount: unknown filesystem type 'nfsd'
```

Please help

Comment: Which OS/Distro is is this ?

Comment: What virtualization tech is this? Post the output of `virt-what`.

Comment: the Distro is Centos 6.4, I already installed the kernel, this is the guide I'm following:
http://serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/storage-file-services/how-to-setup-an-nfs-server-on-centos-6

Answer (score 0):

try to make one disk as nfs-kernel-server and connect from second server to first, try that:
on server install `apt-get install nfs-kernel-server`
after that edit config file in `/etc/exports`

On client install `apt-get install nfs-common` and connect to folder with

```
mount 12.34.56.78:/external/folder /home/second
```